# React "fetch" method not talking to java based Controller

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, controller, fetch

I am attempting to get some data from a database to load into a React based component in my front end. In order to do this, I have created a fetch request that talks to a java based controller on the backend that then eventually hits the database and pulls the information from the database. However, when I attempt to maven build the project, it fails repeatedly and provides the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" which from searching implies a Promise isn't being returned by the fetch request.

My assumption based on several tests is that my fetch request isn't actually being directed to my controller somehow (and debugging the build fails to hit a breakpoint within the controller as well). Looking for any assistance to see why these two pieces aren't talking to each other.

I should also mention I have an insert method in the same view portion that talks to the same controller and that works successfully.

Controller Portion:

```
@Component
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/process/")
public class ProcessController {
  private final ProcessService processService;
  
  @Autowired
  public ProcessController(ProcessService processService) { this.processService = processService; }

  @RequestMapping(value="add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<String> insertProcess(@RequestBody() String processJson) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Process process = gson.fromJson(processJson, Process.class);
    try {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(gson.toJson(processService.insertProcess(process)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }  catch(DataAccessException de) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(de.getCause().getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="select", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<String> selectProcesses() {
    try {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(new Gson().toJson(processService.selectProcesses()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }  catch(DataAccessException de) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(de.getCause().getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }
}
```

And the fetch calls:

```
class ProcessApi {
  static addProcess(processJson) {
    return fetch('/api/process/add', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: processJson
    })
      .then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200) {
          return response.json()
            .then(jsonData => {
              return jsonData;
           });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        return error.json();
      });
  };

  static getProcesses() {
    return fetch('/api/process/select', {
      method: 'POST'
    })
      .then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200) {
          return response.json()
            .then(jsonData => {
              return jsonData;
           });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        return error.json();
      });
  };
}
```

As mentioned, the "addProcess" portion works just fine. The select just isn't connecting up and I can't seem to find out why. For reference I have the API call happening in the componentDidMount() method in my view portion.

Comment: Did you check the Network tab whether the request is even made?

Comment: I am unable to deploy the jar containing the project until it builds successfully. It's failing the build when it hits the fetch call.

Comment: @ConnorMcDevitt are you saying this is a build issue, and not a runtime logic issue? If it's failing the build can you show the build failure logs?